# Removing full stop after first name initial in biblatex, for all authors

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am using biblatex to format my references and I want to format them according to

```
<LastName> <FirstNameInitial>, <LastName> <FirstNameInitial>
```

and so on. In order to remove the standard dot/fullstop after the initial I have tried to use
[Modify the last-name first-name separator in biblatex's authortitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/modify-the-last-name-first-name-separator-in-biblatexs-authortitle)

The problem here is that it only formats the first author after the desired standard. A minimum working example (copied from the above question) is given below. I am almost sure that it is some small part of the answer given in the linked question that needs to be changed, but my biblatex coding skills are at a minium. A picture of the output code is shown in the above linked question but I can not post it here.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@ARTICLE{liu:11,
  author = {Peter Fox and Richard Rabbit and Franc Bird},
  title = {Animals are the better humans},
  journal = {Horse and Hound},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {10},
  pages = {11--15}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\def\MKbibnamefirst#1{\expandafter\mkbibnamefirst@i#1..\@nil}
\def\mkbibnamefirst@i#1.#2.#3\@nil{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
     {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\addhighpenspace}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnamefirst{#2}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\addcomma}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\addlowpenspace\MKbibnamefirst{#2}}%
%     \ifblank{#3}{}{\addlowpenspace\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}
}}
\makeatother
\bibliography{sample}
\begin{document}
Samplecite~\cite{liu:11}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Biblatex: remove commas between last and first names in bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/biblatex-remove-commas-between-last-and-first-names-in-bibliography)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out by Audrey in a comment, one should amend the solution linked in the OP's comment with setting `terseinits=true` and tinkering with `\DeclareNameAlias` for the name sorting order.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,firstinits=true,terseinits=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
     {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%      \ifblank{#2}{}{\addcomma\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}% DELETED
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}% NEW
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
%      \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\addcomma}% DELETED
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{liu:11,
  author = {Peter Fox and Richard Rabbit and Franc Bird},
  title = {Animals are the better humans},
  journal = {Horse and Hound},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {10},
  pages = {11--15}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP also wants *all* authors to be listed as `Surname, FirstInit`, not just the first one.

Comment: @Mico: Indeed. MWE updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it has pointed me in the correct directions but two things: 1) If I copy paste your example I still see the . after the initial. I am unsure of the reason but think it is some strange setting on my computer, will investigate. 2) I would also like to remove the extra comma after the surname of the author: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17583/biblatex-remove-commas-between-last-and-first-names-in-bibliography

Comment: @schr I updated my answer.

Comment: @lockstep Redefining `\bibinitperiod` only works for `biber` and won't suppress dots in hyphenated first names. Enabling `terseinits` as in your duplicate(?) solution is preferable. Suppressing commas should be easier with a dedicated punctuation command added to 2.1.